# RStudio console stops returning to console after running script

Tags: r, rstudio

My question is similar to that in post ([R studio will occasionally stop returning to the console until I restart the program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25598360/r-studio-will-occasionally-stop-returning-to-the-console-until-i-restart-the-pro)). But it doesn't answer my question.

Following is the situation in my RStudio console:

```
> require(igraph)
Loading required package: igraph
> V(T)
Vertex sequence:
[1] 1 2 3 4
> debugSource('C:/current/CSC791/Week 9/P5/P5_kbansal.r')
Browse[1]> n
Browse[2]> c
Error: (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'logical'
> V(T)
>
```

So, even if the '>' cursor has arrived (as answered in similar post), still I am not able to see the variables (e.g. V(T)).

Note: This is not related to the script being successful or erroneous. As I am facing the same with running even R scripts without any error.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try getting output back to console with sink().